# How do I create a horizontally centered "gravity line"?

Tags: java, android, libgdx, box2d

[image: depiction]

Here's my ideal scenario: A game object (in blue) can change its horizontal velocity, but it will be pulled back by gravity (dotted gray arrows) toward a central vertical line (in red).

How can I do this?

Comment: I made a big edit to highlight the question's core. Did I miss any really important details?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have variable centerlineX.
If the sprite is to the left of it, accelerate with a 'gravity' vector, e.g. 9.81.
And vice versa for the other side.

Presumably this should result in the sprite oscillating back and forth for ever, so you will need to add something to the mix to slow it down at a pleasing rate.

Comment: I have one problem... how to I create the center line variable? Thanks for the advice!

Comment: Get the screen width and divide by two.

Answer (score 0):

As karmington suggested, halve the screen width. Be sure to use a getter / setter to do this accordingl to the device's screen specs.

As for gravity, you would want to have a method within your update loop that checks the `x` position of your game object so when `gameObject.x` is less than `centerLine.x`, your gravity is multiplied by `-1`, flipping its direction and making the the `gameObject` move appropriately.